# Unable to get latest value from React State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

This is my React Component. and when I enter total 6 digits in Otp Input; the `onComplete` method is getting invoked which will trigger `handleSubmit` function and It should print the latest value of state `otp`. But it is just printing 5 digits of input. How to solve this ?

```js
function OtpForm() {

    const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit() {
        console.log(otp);
    };

    return (
        <form>
            <MuiOtpInput
                value={otp}
                onChange={(val) => { setOtp(val); }}
                validateChar={(val) => !isNaN(val)}
                onComplete={() => { handleSubmit(); }}
                length={6}
            />
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: seems like it's triggering ON (not after) the 6th input. If the value you want is 6 and it console.logs and stores that correctly after setting the `length={7}` but i would also argue that can be confusing to understand later, so perhaps the issue is somewhere in `MuiOtpInput` functionality... are you doing anything like `>= 6` in there when determining when to trigger onComplete?

Comment: Yeah ! that's what I thought. It has to be the problem of a package. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

By using `useEffect` with `[otp]` as its dependency array, the `handleSubmit` function will be triggered whenever the `otp` state changes. This ensures that handleSubmit will have access to the latest value of `otp`. Also, remove the call to `handleSubmit` from the `onComplete` prop, as it's now handled by the `useEffect` hook.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function OtpForm() {

    const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        //--->This will trigger every time 'otp' changes
        handleSubmit();
    }, [otp]); //--->Watching for changes in 'otp'

    function handleSubmit() {
        console.log(otp);
    };

    return (
        <form>
            <MuiOtpInput
                value={otp}
                onChange={(val) => { setOtp(val); }}
                validateChar={(val) => !isNaN(val)}
                onComplete={() => { /* No need for handleSubmit here */ }}
                length={6}
            />
        </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In tbis code the setOtp function takes a callback that receives the previous state as an argument. This ensures that you're using the latest state when updating it. In the onComplete handler, I've modified it to pass the previous OTP value to the handleSubmit function.

Try this code:-

```
function OtpForm() {
    const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit() {
        console.log(otp);
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <MuiOtpInput
                value={otp}
                onChange={(val) => { setOtp(val); }}
                validateChar={(val) => !isNaN(val)}
                onComplete={() => { setOtp((prevOtp) => { handleSubmit(prevOtp); }); }}
                length={6}
            />
        </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't update the state until it renders again, and considering changing state is asynchronous, it takes a bit time to update the value, thats why you are not getting the latest value. Best way is to update it using a callback function, so it would reflect the latest value, so your code would be like thisL

```
function OtpForm() {

const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');

function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(otp);
};

return (
    <form>
        <MuiOtpInput
            value={otp}
            onChange={(val) => { setOtp(()=>val); }}
            validateChar={(val) => !isNaN(val)}
            onComplete={() => { handleSubmit(); }}
            length={6}
        />
    </form>
);
```

}